# JSON key set to List conversion using deserializeUntyped

Tags: json, list, deserialize

I am trying to extract the 'key' from a json an insert each key to a list (array).

```
Map<String,Object> obj = (Map<String,Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(reqestObj);
List<String> searchFields = new List<String>(); 
searchFields=String.valueOf(obj.keyset().clone()).split(',');
        System.debug('searchFields==='+String.valueOf(obj.keyset().clone()).split(','));
System.debug('POINT 1==='+searchFields.get(0)); 
System.debug('POINT 2==='+searchFields.get(1));
System.debug('POINT 3==='+searchFields.get(2));
```

Suppose below is the *reqestObj* json

> {"State":"AZ","OmniId":"72211800000642952","City":"234234"}

When i debug *searchFields* gets the following:

> searchFields===({City,  OmniId,  State})

Again when i tried to debug each individual element in the *searchFields* find an extra **brace**.

> POINT 1==={City
>
> POINT 2=== OmniId
>
> POINT 3=== State}

Please help me to get rid of that. I believe there is a simple way of extracting the required value without using extra valriabe or using replaceAll() function etc.

Comment: Once you have the keyset, which gives you list of keys, any reason you are joining to a string and then split?

Comment: nope. I just want the keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to do any of that string conversion mechanic to convert a `Set<String>` to a `List<String>`. The [List class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_list.htm) has a constructor that creates the `List` from a `Set`:

```
public List<T>(Set<T> setToCopy)
```

Just do

```
List<String> searchFields = new List<String>(obj.keySet());
```

Answer (score 2):

While David's answer give you correct way to do it, I want to highlight why you get `{` in the output.

When you do `String.valueOf(obj.keyset().clone())` it creates a string which looks like `{<contents of list/set>}` and then when you split, first entry includes `{` and last entry includes `}`.